# Подскажите почему не отрабатывает запрос

Tags: mysql

Пытаюсь отладить будущий триггер
Пример надуманый и очень простой
делаю

```
begin
  IF (1<>0) THEN
    select * from aa.csv;
  ELSE
    select * from aa.csv;
  END IF;
end
```

Но не отрабатывает возвращает ошибку

> Unrecognized statement type. (near "begin" at position 0)
>
> `begin IF (1<>0) THEN select * from aa.csv`
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (1<>0) THEN
> select * from aa.csv' at line 2

При этом, у других судя по всему все прекрасно работает (пример взят с форума где у человека все прекрасно работает) - запрос вроде бы простой до тупости...

Подскажите почему не отрабатывает?

MySQL - 5.7

Comment: Что Вы пытаетесь сделать этим кодом и как его запускаете? Это у Вас процедура?

Comment: В MySQL нет анонимного кода. Вообще. И блоки могут существовать только внутри процедурных структур (процедуры, функции, триггеры и т.п.). *При этом, у других судя по всему все прекрасно работает* Или внутри процедуры (судя по тексту - триггера), или не в MySQL. Но не в консоли.

Comment: Да... запихнул в процедуру все заработало - спасибо...